# How is deterministic state transfer related to entanglement generation between two qubits?

Tags: quantum-information, superconductivity, quantum-computer

From a quantum information theoretical point of view, how is deterministic state transfer related to entanglement generation between two qubits? Or, more specifically, how can you exploit the former to achieve the latter? Would such entaglements protocols be suitable for superconducting xmon qubits? If yes, how?

Comment: do you have reason to believe they are related?

Comment: @glS I read a few experimental physics papers where they claim achieving Bell state generation via deterministic state transfer, using superconducting qubits. However, these publications don't go into details of this procedure

Comment: then you should link those in the post, highlight the relevant statements and detail what you find unclear about them

Comment: There is no relevant statements to highlight as these papers basically take the theoretical  protocol, about which I'm asking, for granted and go on with experimental precedures to perform it in given systems